# Function "addcyclic": IndexError

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib-basemap, index-error

I am using "addcyclic" function and encounter the Index Error. Error details are:

> ```
> IndexError Traceback (most recent call last)
> ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_11852/1134487354.py in
> 6 m.drawmeridians(np.arange(0.,360.,90.),linewidth=0.4,color='gray',labels=[True,True,True,True])
> 7 #在Py3.7下使用basemap==1.2.0，在循环填白addcyclic时可能会报错
> ----> 8 psi_p1,lon1=addcyclic(np.array(psi_p),np.array(lon))
> 9 lonsn, latsn = np.meshgrid(lon1, lat)
> 10 x_cyc,y_cyc=m(lonsn,latsn) #建立投影坐标映射
>
> D:\AnacondaSoftware\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\basemap_init_.py in addcyclic(*arr, **kwargs)
> 5101 return _addcyclic_lon(arr[-1])
> 5102 else:
> -> 5103 return list(map(_addcyclic,arr[:-1])) + [_addcyclic_lon(arr[-1])]
> 5104
> 5105 def _choosecorners(width,height,**kwargs):
>
> D:\AnacondaSoftware\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\basemap_init_.py in _addcyclic(a)
> 5086 raise ValueError('The specified axis does not correspond to an '
> 5087 'array dimension.')
> -> 5088 return npsel.concatenate((a,a[slicer]),axis=axis)
> 5089 def _addcyclic_lon(a):
> 5090 """addcyclic function for a single longitude array"""
>
> IndexError: only integers, slices (:), ellipsis (...), numpy.newaxis (None) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
> ```

The code is:
`psi_p1,lon1=addcyclic(np.array(psi_p),np.array(lon))`

Here is the variable *psi_p*: https://box.nju.edu.cn/f/64583aedd0c24eae909d/
*lon*: https://box.nju.edu.cn/f/a273d137b454468c8007/

Software and module versions are: Python 3.8.8, numpy 1.23.5, basemap: 1.2.2

I am wondering whether it is due to inconsistency of package version? Is it possible to fix the bug without reinstall python or modules due to interdependence of a lot of my other modules. Thanks a lot!!